# How to make simple control of MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, overlay, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm making app using MPMoviePlayerController. This capture is pic of a my reference app. I want to make like red boxed part. - only Done button and progress bar. How can I make like this?

Can I solve thereby I add some options in MPMoviePlayerController or I add overlay view include some controls?

I can't find the good way. Please help!~ and Thanks!

[image: Media]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own controls, then add them to the overlay view...